# Combining kinetic.js and three.js af kinetic.js v 5?

Tags: three.js

Read the article:
http://architects.dzone.com/articles/combining-threejs-and

It seems however thay after kinetic.js v. 5-> this solution doesn't work anymore.
Has anyone been able to find a workaround?

Best regards and thank you

Jens

Answer (score 0):

Three.js used canvas element
so used jquery to get the canvas used by kineti.js stage as shown in following code.

```
    <script>
        var camera, scene, renderer, geometry, material, mesh;
        var stage, layer3D, layerGUI;
        var animating = true;

        function init() {
            stage = new Kinetic.Stage({container: "container", width: 700, height: 700});
            layer3D = new Kinetic.Layer();
            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, 600 / 600, 1, 10000);
            camera.position.z = 1000;
            scene.add(camera);

            geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(200, 200, 200);
            material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000, wireframe: true });

            mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            scene.add(mesh);

            stage.add(layer3D);

            var canvas= layer3D.getCanvas();
            canvas = $("#container canvas").get(0);
            console.log( canvas );
            console.log( layer3D );
            renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer({ canvas: canvas });


            renderer.setSize(700, 700);

            var group = new Kinetic.Group({ draggable: true });
            layerGUI = new Kinetic.Layer();

            layerGUI.add(group);


            stage.add(layerGUI);
            render();
        }

        function animate() {
            // note: three.js includes requestAnimationFrame shim
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            render();
        }

        function render() {
            if (animating) {
                mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
                mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;
            }

            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            layerGUI.draw();
        }

        $(function () {
            init();
            animate();
        });
    </script>
```

Here canvas = $("#container canvas").get(0); is used to fetch the canvas of kinetic.js container.